# Cannot make the form.

Tags: php, html, mysql

I want to do the following. I input value and click submit. If the value is outside of the range 0 and 299 save the text 'blabla' into the variable $error. If it is in the range of 0 and 299 to update the value into the MySQL table (row - SkinID);
Here is what I've tried and didn't work.
This is my HTML form:

```
<form action="skinid.php" method="POST">
                            <!--<fieldset class="textarea-field">
                                <textarea title="Message">Message</textarea>
                            </fieldset>-->
<br>
                            <fieldset>
                                <span class="ico user-ico"></span>
                                <input name="skinid" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" type="text" class="field" value="Enter new Skin ID. (-2000$)" title="Enter new Skin ID. (-2000$)" />
                            </fieldset>
                            <center><input type="submit" class="submit btn blue-btn" value="Update" /></center>
                        </form>
  <?php $_SESSION['skinid'] = $_POST['skinid']; ?>
```

This is the skinid.php file:

```
<?php
session_start();
$newskinid = $_SESSION['skinid'];
if($newskinid < '0' || $newskinid > '299'){$error = 'The Skin ID must be in the range of 0 and 299.';}
else {
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","USERNAME","PASSWORD","DB-NAME");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE users SET SkinID=$newskinid
WHERE Username='$_SESSION[user]'");
mysqli_close($con);}
?>
```

Comment: use `$_POST['skinid']` instead of `$_SESSION['skinid']` in `skinid.php`

Comment: Well what didn't work? Did php respond correctly and the database didn't do what you wanted? php $_SESSION['skinid'] = $_POST['skinid'];

Comment: What about it doesn't work? Do you get a MySQL error or 'The skin ID must be in the range of 0 and 299.'?

Comment: Friendly reminder - you shouldn't build SQL queries by concatenating strings like that without at least cleaning user input.

Comment: @NicholasPickering erm.... he isn't concatenating above.

Comment: @itachi I've done it and is still not updating the value in the mysql table.

Comment: @itachi Is interpolating any safer than concatenation? The concept is the same, the strings are being "stitched" together and queries built this way are vulnerable, without the proper cleaning.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try skinid.php:

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['skinid'] = $_POST['skinid']; 
$newskinid = $_SESSION['skinid'];
if($newskinid < '0' || $newskinid > '299') {
    echo 'The Skin ID must be in the range of 0 and 299.';
}
else {
    echo 'dhgj';
}
?>
<form method="post">

<br>
<fieldset>
    <span class="ico user-ico"></span>
    <input name="skinid" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" type="text" class="field" value="Enter new Skin ID. (-2000$)" title="Enter new Skin ID. (-2000$)" />
</fieldset>
<center><input type="submit" class="submit btn blue-btn" value="Update" /></center>
</form>
```

Comment: you should mention it that the above html code is valid for html5 only.

Answer (score 3):

Unless the first code sample is also from skinid.php, in the HTML form your `$_POST['skinid']` is empty, and consequently in skinid.php your `$_SESSION['skinid']` will also be empty.

Instead, in skinid.php use:
`$newskinid = $_POST['skinid'];`

Comment: My table is MySQL, not MySQLi, can that be a problem?

Comment: there is no `mysqli` table type of thingy.